# com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init> The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jersey

I am facing some problem while uploading war file to AWS Tomcat8 Server.

Project Type: Dynamic Web Project;
Tomcat: Version - 8;
Java: Version 1.8

It was working perfectly before I added some code for File Upload and Download Operation to AWS S3 Instance using Java.

> 13-May-2017 19:29:55.770 INFO [http-nio-8088-exec-3]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. 13-May-2017 19:29:55.784 INFO
>   [http-nio-8088-exec-3]
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root
>   resource and provider classes in the packages:
>   com.harsha.app.services 13-May-2017 19:29:55.881 INFO
>   [http-nio-8088-exec-3]
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate
>   Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016
>   02:08 PM' 13-May-2017 19:29:56.304 SEVERE [http-nio-8088-exec-3]
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules. The
>   ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
>   13-May-2017 19:29:56.313 INFO [http-nio-8088-exec-3]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   8.0\webapps\harsha.war has finished in 6,475 ms

AmazonS3Operation Class:

```
package com.harsha.app.servlet.file;

import java.io.File;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.harsha.app.constant.Constant;

public class AmazonS3DriveOperation {

    AWSCredentials credentials;
    AmazonS3 s3Client;

    public AmazonS3DriveOperation() {
        s3Authorization();
    }

    public void s3Authorization() {
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Constant.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constant.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    }

    public void s3FileUpload(String bucketName, String fileName, File file) {
        s3Client.putObject(bucketName, fileName, file);
    }

    public S3Object s3FileDownload(String bucketName, String fileName) {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName);
        S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(request);
        return s3Object;
    }

    public boolean s3FileDelete(String bucketName, String fileName) {
        try {
            DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName);
            s3Client.deleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
            return true;
        }
        catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

DataDeleteServlet Class:

```
package com.harsha.app.servlet.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.harsha.app.constant.Constant;
import com.harsha.app.database.DBManager;
import com.harsha.app.database.DataUpload;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DataFileDelete
 */
@WebServlet("/DataFileDelete")
public class DataFileDelete extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DataFileDelete() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        String filePath = Constant.DATA_DRIVE + fileName;
        String serverDocumentsId = request.getParameter("serverDocumentsId");

        fileName = Constant.BASE_UPLOAD_FOLDER + Constant.SUFFIX + fileName;

        DBManager dbManager = new DBManager();
        System.out.println(filePath);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("adminUploadExcel.jsp");
        AmazonS3DriveOperation amazon = new AmazonS3DriveOperation();
        if(amazon.s3FileDelete(Constant.BUCKET_NAME, fileName)) {
            DataUpload.deleteFileFromServer(serverDocumentsId, dbManager);
            System.out.println("Done");
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Data Delete Successful");
        }
        else {
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Data Delete Unsuccessful");
            System.out.println("Not Done");
        }
        dbManager.close();
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

DataFileUploadDownload Servlet Class:

```
package com.harsha.app.servlet.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.harsha.app.constant.Constant;
import com.harsha.app.database.DBManager;
import com.harsha.app.database.DataUpload;
import com.harsha.app.util.ExcelRead;

@WebServlet(name = "DataFileUploadDownload",urlPatterns = {"/DataFileUploadDownload/*"})
public class DataFileUploadDownload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int BUFFER_LENGTH = 4096;

    String fileNameAssigned = "";
    String fileNameGiven = "";
    String excelType = "";



    public DataFileUploadDownload() {
        super();
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String filePath = request.getRequestURI();

        String fileName = filePath.replace(Constant.REPLACE_URL,"");                
        AmazonS3DriveOperation amazon = new AmazonS3DriveOperation();

        fileName = Constant.BASE_UPLOAD_FOLDER + Constant.SUFFIX + fileName;

        S3Object s3Object = amazon.s3FileDownload(Constant.BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
        InputStream input = s3Object.getObjectContent();

        response.setContentLength((int) s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength());
        response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType()));

        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = input.read(bytes, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
            output.write(bytes, 0, read);
            output.flush();
        }

        input.close();
        output.close();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        DBManager dbManager = new DBManager();
        out.println("Hello<br/>");

        boolean isMultipartContent = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if (!isMultipartContent) {
            out.println("You are not trying to upload<br/>");
            return;
        }
        out.println("You are trying to upload<br/>");

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        try {
            List<FileItem> fields = upload.parseRequest(request);
            out.println("Number of fields: " + fields.size() + "<br/><br/>");
            Iterator<FileItem> it = fields.iterator();
            if (!it.hasNext()) {
                out.println("No fields found");
                return;
            }
            out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                out.println("<tr>");
                FileItem fileItem = it.next();
                boolean isFormField = fileItem.isFormField();
                if (isFormField) {
                    out.println("<td>regular form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() + 
                            "<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString()
                            );
                    out.println("</td>");
                    if(fileItem.getFieldName().equals("fileName"))
                        excelType = fileItem.getString();
                } else {
                    out.println("<td>file form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() +
                            //"<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString() +
                            "<br/>NAME: " + fileItem.getName() +
                            "<br/>CONTENT TYPE: " + fileItem.getContentType() +
                            "<br/>SIZE (BYTES): " + fileItem.getSize() +
                            "<br/>TO STRING: " + fileItem.toString()
                            );
                      fileNameGiven = fileItem.getName();
                     fileNameAssigned = DataUpload.getCurrentTime() + "" + getFileName(fileNameGiven);
                    String path = Constant.DATA_DRIVE + ""+ fileNameAssigned;
                    System.out.println(path);

                    //File fileUpload = new File(path);

                    fileNameAssigned = Constant.BASE_UPLOAD_FOLDER + Constant.SUFFIX + fileNameAssigned;

                    File file = new File(fileNameAssigned);
                    fileItem.write(file);
                    AmazonS3DriveOperation amazon = new AmazonS3DriveOperation();
                    amazon.s3FileUpload(Constant.BUCKET_NAME, fileNameAssigned, file);
                    out.println("</td>");
                }
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table>");
            DataUpload.insertNewUploadFileDetails(fileNameGiven, fileNameAssigned, dbManager);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        uploadExcelData(fileNameAssigned, excelType, dbManager);
        dbManager.close();
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("adminUploadExcel.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("msg", "Data Upload Successful");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    private String getFileName(String fileName) {
        return fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf('.')).trim();
    }

    private void uploadExcelData(String fileNameAssigned, String excelType, DBManager dbManager) throws IOException {
        ExcelRead er = new ExcelRead();
        if(excelType.equals("Family")) {
            JSONArray jArray = er.readBooksFromExcelFile(fileNameAssigned, excelType);
            DataUpload.uploadFamilyArchieve(jArray, dbManager);
        }           
        else if(excelType.equals("Member")) {
            JSONArray jArray = er.readBooksFromExcelFile(fileNameAssigned, excelType);
            DataUpload.uploadMemberArchieve(jArray, dbManager);
        }           
    }

}
```

ExcelFileCreating and Download Servlet Class:

```
package com.harsha.app.servlet.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.harsha.app.constant.Constant;
import com.harsha.app.database.DBHandler;
import com.harsha.app.database.DBManager;
import com.harsha.app.util.ExcelRead;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TableDataDownload
 */
@WebServlet(name = "TableDataDownload",urlPatterns = {"/TableDataDownload/*"})
public class TableDataDownload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int BUFFER_LENGTH = 4096;

String fileNameAssigned = "";
String fileNameGiven = "";
String excelType = "";


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TableDataDownload() {
        super();
    }

    public JSONArray agricultureImpactReport() {
        DBManager dbManager=new DBManager();
        JSONArray jsonArray = DBHandler.getAgricultureImpactReport(0, new Date().getTime()/1000, dbManager);
        dbManager.close();
        return jsonArray;
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filePath = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println(filePath);

        String impactName = filePath.replace(Constant.REPLACE_URL2,"");
        System.out.println(impactName);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        if(impactName.equals("agriculture.xls")) {
            jsonArray = agricultureImpactReport();
            filePath = ExcelRead.generateExcelReport(jsonArray, impactName);
        }           
        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
        System.out.println("filepath=" + filePath);
        String path = Constant.DATA_DRIVE + filePath;
        System.out.println("path=" + path);

        String fileName = filePath;
        /*File file = new File(path);
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));
        */

        fileName = Constant.BASE_UPLOAD_FOLDER + Constant.SUFFIX + fileName;
        AmazonS3DriveOperation amazon = new AmazonS3DriveOperation();

        S3Object s3Object = amazon.s3FileDownload(Constant.BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
        InputStream input = s3Object.getObjectContent();

        response.setContentLength((int) s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength());
        response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType()));

        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = input.read(bytes, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
            output.write(bytes, 0, read);
            output.flush();
        }

        input.close();
        output.close();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Yushu</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.harsha.app.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[List of Jar Configured in Project. All present in lib folder under WEB-INF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIt8q.png)

Dependencies in my pom.ml:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.127</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.127</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
              <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
              <version>1.4.5</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
      <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried many solutions like:

- Including Jar Files for every API.
- Including dependencies for maven in pom.
- Checking Web.xml for Jersey Servlet Container and the Services root
  packkage.
- Checking for similr URL for more than 1 service which create
  ambiguity.
- Java and Tomcat Version Checked. AWS and my locak machine version are
  mathcing.

**Still the bug not fixed. Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use Jersey, why are you using Servlets? This is not how Jersey works. With Jersey, you have resource classes annotated with `@Path`. For example

```
package com.harsha.app.services;

@Path("pets")
public class PetsResource {
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Pet get(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        ...
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response create(Pet pet) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice the package at the top. Jersey will scan that package (because that's the package you configured in your web.xml) for classes annotated with `@Path`, so it can register it as a *resource class*. This is why you are getting the error message "there are no root resource classes".

I am not even going to try to explain what the code above does. It is too broad a topic. You will need to go through some tutorials and documentation to really learn this stuff. But what you are currently doing is completely wrong.

Comment: But I have been using it for a long time and its working perfectly but when I added Amazon S3 Operation Codes it started producing the errors.

Comment: Ok, well looking at the message again that you posted, it is not an error of any kind. It is just an INFO message, telling you that Jersey is not configured with any resource classes. So when you had it "working" before, it was not using Jersey. It was just using plain servlets. I don't even know why you have Jersey dependencies and are trying to configure Jersey in your web.xml. It makes no sense to me. I don't know why your servlets are not working. All I can say is that if you actually do want to use Jersey, you need to make a _lot_ of changes.